# Python Pandas Dataframe filter and replace

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I constructed a dataframe which looks like this:

```
title category1 category2 category3 category4
'a'    0.44214    NAN        0.99     0.35
'b'      NAN      NAN        NAN       NAN
'c'      0.31      0.41       0.5       0.53
```

For each row, I want to indicate the two highest values with 1 and all others with 0.

Result should look like this:

```
 title category1 category2 category3 category4
'a'    1           0          1         0
'b'    0           0          0         0
'c'    0           0          1         1
```

Is there a buildin-function solve this or how could this be implemented otherwise?

Comment: What if the numbers are 0.9, 0.9, 0.8, 0.8?  What would you want to happen?  What if the numbers are 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.8?  (In other words, how do you want to handle ties?)

Comment: Very unlikely case because these numbers are random floats. But if it happens it should take two of these highest numbers and replace them with 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rank the rows (setting `axis=1`) in descending order all numeric values in the dataframe.  Then do a boolean comparison to find the rank values less than or equal to two (`le(2)`), which would be rank values 1 and 2.  Finally, convert the boolean mask to integers.

```
>>> df.rank(axis=1, ascending=False, numeric_only=True).le(2).astype(int)
       category1  category2  category3  category4
title                                            
'a'            1          0          1          0
'b'            0          0          0          0
'c'            0          0          1          1
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but unfortunately your solutions seems not to work. Printing the result returns : Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [0, 1]

Comment: Are you sure your dataframe contains values instead of text?  What is the output of `df.info()`?

Comment: Oh you're right. Thanks. I converted to dtype=float and everything works fine. Really fancy solution. Thanks